Sum of multiple piecewise function, find x so that the sum is biggest
$f_{i}(x) = \begin{cases} 
a_{i}c_{i} + b_{i}, & -0.1< x < c_{i} \\
\\
a_{i}x + b_{i}, & c_{i} \leq x \leq d_{i} \\
\\
      e_{i},& d_{i} <x<0.1
\end{cases}$
Known facts:

$a_{i}>0$
$a_{i}, b_{i}, c_{i}, d_{i}, e_{i}$ are all constants in each $f_{i}(x)$, it's just that each function has its own set of constants, and they can be different
$a_{i}d_{i} + b_{i} > e_{i}$, which means when $x = d_{i}$, the function reaches its max value: $a_{i}d_{i} + b_{i}$
$e_{i}$ could be bigger or smaller than $a_{i}c_{i} + b_{i}$, but both are always smaller than $a_{i}d_{i} + b_{i}$

Sum of these piecewise functions: $$S = \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x)$$
Now how to find x so that S reaches its max value?

Please show us what you have tried so far. Is this homework ? If so please use the [tag:self-study] tag. If not, please let us know how this arises and what the motivation is.

Man, this is SO not homework... Basically it's different temperatures (x) of a material's performance on different scenerios(could be hundreds of thousands), in each scenerio it pretty much follows such piecewise function. And I'm trying to search for the x so that the performance in general is the best. Enemerating is just way too much work, even only on all $d_{i}$, so maybe there's an equation or some algorithm to use instead of enumerating?

Got it, thanks for clarifying. It’s quite a tricky constrained optimisation problem. I’ll try to have a go at it a bit later .

You've double-defined the value at $d_i$; which one did you want? And do you mean to exclude $\pm0.1$ (and are $c_i, d_i$ strictly between those endpoints)?

@BenReiniger: Sorry for the value at $d_{i}$, just edited. And yes x value excludes ±0.1 and $c_{i}, d_{i}$ are strictly between those endpoints

As you mentioned that x are temperatures, I was wondering if your real data range for x is really as small as [-0.1, 0.1] or it is after some kind of normalization? also what is the degree of precision you need for S and corresponding x? and is only the max of S is important or also the corresponding x ?

@rehaqds Yeah it's normallized into [-0.1, 0.1].  Honestly at the beginning I thought it might be a pure math problem with a definitive equation which could be used instead of enumerating and comparing sums. And now from the answers I got, the euqation might not exist(or maybe too complicated?). We want the correct/official x in any batch of scenerios, it's more like if equation or better optimiations being used, the larger batch of scenerios could be applied.

The maximum of a piecewise-continuous function (like $S$) on an interval (if a maximum exists) occurs at either an endpoint or a critical point. For a piecewise-linear function (like $S$), there are no critical points with derivative zero*, so we can limit our search to just endpoints of the linear pieces.
*excepting where the function is locally constant, but if a maximum exists there it will also occur at the endpoints of that interval.
So, just check the values of $S$ at $-0.1, 0.1,$ and each $c_i, d_i$. Depending on how your discontinuities actually behave (I'll add a clarifying question in a comment), there might not be a maximum. If you want the supremum, I think you can just check values at $c_i\pm\varepsilon$ and $d_i\pm\varepsilon$ for very small $\varepsilon$ (relative to the known constants) to identify which point the supremum is approached at.

So far we haven't used many of the additional known facts.
On the intervals $(-0.1, d_i]$, $f_i$ is continuous and nondecreasing; so we don't actually need to check any of the $c_i$.
Since the value at the jump discontinuities is from the left, the value of $S$ at any $d_i$ is a local maximum ($S$ is continuous with slope $>0$ from the left, and has a discontinuous drop to the right). So we don't need to worry about failing to achieve a maximum, nor with checking $d_i\pm\varepsilon$s.
Finally, we don't need to check the ends either: The smallest $d_i$ is better than $-0.1$, and the largest $d_i$ is better than $0.1$.
So just check $S(d_i)$ for all $i$.

Thanks for the explanation! I was wondering, if $f_{i}(x)$ value are strictly limited to  a range like (-1, 1), is there a way to further zooming in on even smaller amount of $d_{i}$? maybe if when most $d_{i}$ are in some certain ranges?

@Shane I'm pretty sure one could construct examples where any of the $d_i$ are the maximum point. Putting a cap on the ranges of $f_i$ won't help, because we can scale all of them after constructing an example. I don't think constraint the locations of $d_i$ helps either. Some limit on the coefficients relative to each other may help.

Below I outline a computational approach using numpy. There is scope to optimize it for speed if required. I have found it to work well in its current form.

Interpolate each function onto a common axis
Stack them into an array and sum over the stacked dimension
Locate the index where the result is maximum.

Two potential issues with this approach are:

Interpolation could be slow

But since they're independent, you could parallelize this quite easily using numba, or take a batch-processing approach.

Also, you don't necessarily need to use all the functions - I think there is a case for sampling a smaller representative subset.



You need to 'tune' the resolution. Too coarse and you miss some peaks; too fine and it'll be computationally expensive. I think you could start coarse and then try some finer runs.

Though, since you have a lot of data, individual anomalous peaks don't matter as they will likely average out when you sum/aggregate.



You could set the resolution using statistical features of the data. For example, record the shortest interval for each scenario, and use the global minimum (or the 10% quantile) as the resolution. That helps ensure you interpolate finely enough based on the data's characteristics. My synthetic data has a lot of overlap/smoothing so I didn't spend time tuning the resolution.
Demo using synthetic data
I synthesised one million scenarios ($i=[1..1e6]$) with randomly-selected parameters ($a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i, e_i$) that respect the constraints you described. Three such examples:

I then define the resolution of the common axis onto which all $f_i$ will be interpolated. I used x_resolution = 0.001 in the code based on visual assessment.
It only took a second on my computer so you probably won't need to optimize this step for parallelism using numba.
Finally, the interpolated profiles are averaged (you could equivalently sum them) and $x_{max}$ is identified:

I looped over the scenarios and recorded $d_{i}$ and $f_{max}$ for each case. To make things a bit faster, I first pre-allocated a numpy array for this purpose. You can speed things up further using numba which makes it easy to parallelise loops (current code only took a few seconds so I haven't optimized it further).
The figure below shows the distribution of $f_{max}$ (right margin), $d_i$ (top margin), and their joint distribution. Note that this is for individual scenarios. The max $f$ value over scenarios varies widely for my synthetic data, but they tend to be larger at the upper end of $d_i$. I think a 2D histogram may bring the detail out more clearly.

I subsampled the data for speed. In practice, subsampling (if employed) should probably be stratified to avoid a distorted representation.
Average performance is max at x=-0.013 (performance=0.49)

Reproducible example
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#
# Synthetic for testing
#
n_scenarios = 1000_000

scenarios = []
rng = np.random.RandomState(5)
for i in range(n_scenarios):
    c_i = rng.uniform(-0.1, 0.1 *0.8) #limit max for synthetic data
    d_i = rng.uniform(c_i, 0.1)

    a_i = rng.uniform(1, 4)
    b_i = rng.uniform(0, 1)

    max_val = a_i * d_i + b_i
    e_i = rng.uniform(0, max_val *0.8) #limit max for synthetic data

    epsilon = 1e-6
    x_seg0 = [-0.1, c_i]
    x_seg1 = [c_i + epsilon, d_i]
    x_seg2 = [d_i + epsilon, 0.1]

    seg0 = [a_i * c_i + b_i] * 2
    seg1 = [seg0[1], max_val]
    seg2 = [e_i] * 2

    all_x = x_seg0 + x_seg1 + x_seg2
    all_f = seg0 + seg1 + seg2

    scenarios.append((all_x, all_f))

    #Plot the first three
    if i > 2:
        continue

    ax = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 1.5)).add_subplot()
    ax.plot(
        all_x, all_f,
        marker='s', markersize=4, linewidth=0.5,
    )
    ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='performance', title=f'scenario {i + 1}')
    ax.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)


#
# Interpolate
#

#Set the resolution for interpolating all the profiles
x_resolution = 0.001
x_common = np.arange(-0.1, 0.1 + x_resolution, x_resolution)

#pre-allocate memory
interpolated = np.empty((n_scenarios, len(x_common)))

#Interpolate each scenario onto a common x axis
for i, (x_i, f_i) in enumerate(scenarios):
    interpolated[i] = np.interp(x_common, x_i, f_i)

mean_performance = interpolated.mean(axis=0)
x_max = x_common[mean_performance.argmax()]
print(
    f'Average performance is max at x={x_max:.2} (performance={mean_performance.max():.2f})'
)


#
# Visualise results
#
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3)).add_subplot()

ax.plot(x_common, interpolated[:1000].T, lw=0.1, alpha=0.1, color='black')
ax.plot(x_common, mean_performance, color='darkred', linewidth=2)

#Identify x_max
ax.axvline(x_max, lw=5, alpha=0.4, color='tab:purple', label='$x_{max}$')

#Optionally visualise the spread/standard deviation
ax.fill_between(
    x_common,
    y1=mean_performance - interpolated.std(axis=0),
    y2=mean_performance + interpolated.std(axis=0),
    alpha=0.1, color='red', edgecolor='none', label='standard deviation'
)

#
#Formatting
#
ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='performance', title='Interpolated data')
ax.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)

#Legend
ax.plot([], [], lw=0.8, color='gray', label='individual scenarios')
ax.plot([], [], color='darkred',  label='mean performance')
plt.legend()

Visualise the distributions:
#
# Compute and visualise the distribution of d_i
#

#Pre-allocate a numpy array to store the (d_i, f_max) values
di_and_fmax = np.empty((n_scenarios, 2))

#Loop over scenarios. Each scenario has x values and f(x)
for row, (x, f) in enumerate(scenarios):
    #Find the index where f(x) is max,
    # and use that to index out f_max and d_i
    di_idx = np.argmax(f)
    f_max = f[di_idx]
    d_i = x[di_idx]

    #Write (d_i, f_max) to array
    di_and_fmax[row] = np.array([d_i, f_max])


#
# Visualise distribution of d_i and/or f_max
#
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

max_df = pd.DataFrame(di_and_fmax, columns=['d_i', 'f_max'])

subsample = 20
sample_df = max_df.sample(frac=1.0).iloc[::subsample]

# Scatter plot of d_i and f_max
g = sns.jointplot(sample_df, x='d_i', y='f_max', kind='kde', fill=False, alpha=0.3)
g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot, marker='.', s=2, color='tab:red', alpha=1)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 5)


Nice work Muhammad (+1)

Thank you Robert

Because of the discontinuity, I believe that x_seg2 should be something like x_seg2 = [d_i + 1e-8, 0.1] .

Thanks for pointing that out @rehaqds. I have amended my answer.

Man, thanks a lot for your solution!! So we use polars a lot on data processing, and it seems there's no similar method like numpy.interp (polars' interpolate is quite different), basically when it comes to calc Xmax we'll switch to numpy to do the heavy lifting. Now since Xmax only comes from all $d_{i}$, if $f_{i}(x)$ value has a certain range limit say (-1, 1), can we actually prove that when most $d_{i}$ (like more than 50%) are located in a small range such as (0.03, 0.04), then Xmax must also come from such range? And also would you explain a bit more on how to tune the resolution?

especially on how to start coarse and then zoom in on locating the Xmax if sampling the data or maybe some other way? much appreciated!

My pleasure @Shane Yes, you could visualise the distribution of $d_{i}$, $f_{max}$, and their joint distribution. I have updated the code with an example. I have also elaborated on how one can tune the resolution.

In theory, for 1 million scenarios, a resolution of 0.001 (i.e. 200 points) would be too coarse to find the max, specially if it is on one of the 1 million d_i. But 1M points spread on 0.2 interval is quite huge and because of the plateau on the left part of the curve, in practice it may not make a big difference (depending on the degree of precision needed by the OP).

As Ben Reiniger says the max of S should happen on one of the d_i but can we find which one or at least get an approximation of the max performance ?
One could have the intuition that the max would happen at the smallest d_i.
Because if we rank all the n scenarios with d_i increasing and that we take the first curve and add the second one, as d_2 > d_1 and that after d_1
we have a gap down, the max would be on d_1 and not d_2. And then we can add a third scenario and so on.
And it worked ... on the first 3 tests I made. And then not anymore !
Thinking about it, I realized that it is possible that if we have the max on d_1 with n-1 scenarios, if we add the next scenario (they are ranked with d_i increasing) there is a possibility that a new max happens for example on d_2 if the slope a_n of the new curve added is big enough so that on the interval [d_1, d_2] it can catch up the delay it has because of previous gap down just at the right of d1.
Then I played with MuhammedYunus code (with some updates) and on a dozen of tries (so it's not a proof) it appeared that by taking the value on d_1, we had an approximation of the max value at less than 4% (the higher n the smaller the error).
Also when n, the number of scenarios, increased, d_max (ie d_i for which S is max) increased and we get a longer "plateau". And then, on the plateau (so with only small variation of S), taking d_1 or d_max shouldn't make a lot of difference.
Trying to explain the intuition, when we add more scenarios, d_max can moves to the right if the slope a of the new curve is big enough as seen previously but cannot move to the left as S for d_max will increase more than for smaller d. I guess that's why the value of S on the left of d_max is catching on the value for d_max, it cannot go higher, which leads to a plateau between -0.1 and d_max.
And the more scenarios are added the more chance to have a slope large enough to compensate for the deficit due to previous gaps down and so d_max moves to the right and the plateau length increases.
Approximation of S_max
As seen above the max of value is by definition on d_max but as we have a plateau between d_1 and d_max, the value of S on d_1 should be a good approximation of S_max. And it is not difficult to compute S(d_1).
As for each scenario d_1 can be on the first part of the curve (a_i*c_i+b_i) or on the linear part, we have:
S(d_1) = sum(max(a_i * c_i + b_i, a_i * d_1 + b_i))  with d_1 = min(d_i)
and as the functions are monotonically increasing:
S(d_1) = sum(a_i * max(c_i, d_1)) + sum(b_i)
which gives an easy to compute approximation of the maximum performance
Let's use MohammedYunus code for some visualisations.As we don't have the real data, let's look at 1 example by generating 5000 random scenarios and then sort the scenarios so that they are ranked with increasing d_i.
For the first 5 scenarios:

S max at x=-0.076 (S=7.76)
S at d_1=-0.076 (S=7.76)
For the first 500 scenarios:

S max at x=-0.072 (S=1122.06)
S at d_1=-0.076 (S=1120.12)
For the full 5000 scenarios:

S max at x=-0.049 (S=12490.97)
S at d_1=-0.076 (S=12436.90) so a 0.4% error (on this example).
And also S(-0.1) would also be an approximation of S_max (specially if n tot too small, though not as good as d_1) and even easier to compute as S(-0.1) = sum(a_i * c_i + b_i).
Here, S(-0.1) = 12397 ie 0.7% error
